# Remote - SSH in VSCode issued "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe"

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have successfully connected via ssh to a remote computer. However, when using command line, it showed the below error:

```
CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawn: No such file or directory
```

As I used remote - ssh extension of VS Code to resolve the problem, the output I received was:

```
[20:22:54.051] > kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
> Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

And command "ssh -vvv remote" produced this:

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/thong/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/thong/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for tessera
debug2: checking match for 'Originalhost noibai Exec "ipconfig | grep 10.111.19"' host 10.100.132.101 originally tessera
debug3: /c/Users/thong/.ssh/config line 15: not matched 'Originalhost "tessera"'
debug3: /c/Users/thong/.ssh/config line 15: skipped exec "ipconfig | grep 10.111.19"
debug2: match not found
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.100.132.101 is address
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -q -W 10.100.132.101:22250 hanoi
debug1: identity file C:/Users/thong/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:/Users/thong/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Could anyone help me out of this?